# Regex to fail if a character anywhere before a word but pass if after

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to check a string using regex in PHP. if the string has a character "?" any where before a word then the regex will fail but if "?" is any where after the word then regex will pass. Like, my word is "world" and string is "Hi All? Hello World, How are you". Below are the scenarios.

1. "Hi? All Hello World, How are you". will fail
2. "Hi All? Hello World, How are you". will fail
3. "Hi All Hello? World, How are you". will fail
4. "Hi All Hello World, How? are you". will pass
5. "Hi All Hello World, How are? you". will pass
6. "Hi All Hello World, How are you?". will pass

Comment: Something like this? `^.*[wW]orld.*\?.*$`

Comment: What if there is no `?` at all - should it fail or pass?

Comment: @Vrintle: `.*` will allow a `?` before `World`.

Comment: @TimPietzcker it will pass if there is no "?". I forgot to mention!

Comment: OK, what about `"Hello world, how? are you, world?"` Now we have no `?`  before the first `world` but there is one before the second `world`.

Comment: @TimPietzcker string and position of the word is fixed but only the "?" character is changing its position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to prevent a `?` anywhere before any occurrence of `world`, then a [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) will do the trick:

```
^(?is)(?!.*\?.*world).*
```

`(?is)` turns on case-insensitive matching and allows the dot to match any character including line breaks.